# While handling new tab in cypress, getting error "CypressError: `cy.click()` failed because it requires a DOM element."

Tags: typescript, cypress

While handling new tab in cypress, getting error

```
"CypressError: `cy.click()` failed because it requires a DOM element."
The subject received was:

  > `Object{3}`

The previous command that ran was:

  > `cy.invoke()`
```

I write the below code:

```
cy.xpath("//li[@role='menuitem'][8]//a").invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click();
```

[image]

Comment: Does your xpath return a jquery element?

Comment: yes it seems to return jquery element